# Floated span sticking to one line, but want to flow onto new lines

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a list that uses float to show keys and values on alternative sides of the div.

The problem I'm having is that when there's a long string as a key, which is floated, instead of breaking onto multiple lines, the entire line moves down onto a new line.

Here's an example : http://jsfiddle.net/3djakgf7/

This displays fine, but if there are multiple values after Weight Loss Surgery (for example, 'Weight Loss Surgery, Arm Lift'), that entire line drops down to the next, and then interrupts the flow of the floats below. As in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/3djakgf7/1/

How can I make it so that the float starts on the line opposite the left key, and then drops down to the next line when it runs out of room, and pushes the following list items down a line with it?

```
<ul class="post-meta">
    <li>
        <span class="post-meta-key">Procedure</span>
        <span class="pull-right">Weight Loss Surgery, Arm Lift</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="post-meta-key">Age</span>
        <span class="pull-right">44</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="post-meta-key">Location</span>
        <span class="pull-right">Surrey</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/3djakgf7/3/?

Comment: This seems okay, but previously, the items that were floated, were aligned to the right, where as this seems to cancel that out.

Comment: @Lee also add li :nth-child(2) { text-align: right } in order to keep right alignment, based on j08691

Comment: @Lee there problem is the fixed width on the container width:236px;

Comment: Ok, ignore the fixed width then, that was only to show the line bump happening in the fiddle.

Comment: @Lee will this work for you - http://jsfiddle.net/3djakgf7/5/ (still using float)

Answer (score 0):

Please check your solution below or on updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3djakgf7/2/)

```
ul {
    width: 236px;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
.post-meta-key {
    font-weight: bold;
    float: left;
    width: 76px;
}
.pull-right {
    float: right;
    width: 160px;
}
```

Comment: Do I have to set specific widths? I was hoping to be able to use floats, to keep it responsive.

Comment: Yes you have to set because you set specific width on ul tag

Comment: That was for the purposes of the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative approach using CSS tables.

It works reasonably well provided that the second column is aligned to the right edge of the block.

```css
ul {
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  width: 238px;
  overflow: auto;
}
ul li {
  display: table-row;
}
ul li span {
    border: 1px dotted blue;
}
.post-meta-key {
  font-weight: bold;
  display: table-cell;
}
.pull-right {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<ul class="post-meta">
  <li>
    <span class="post-meta-key">Procedure</span>
    <span class="pull-right">Weight Loss Surgery, Arm Lift</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="post-meta-key">Age</span>
    <span class="pull-right">44</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="post-meta-key">Location</span>
    <span class="pull-right">Surrey</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```